# How do I create a new user on AWS?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, user-management, amazon-web-services

I want to give developers individual access to AWS Management Console, and have their own security keys for AWS command line tools. Is it possible for me to do this using the command line tools? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want AWS [Identity and Access Management system](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/), it does pretty much exactly what you want, including a command line interface and API. However, it doesn't currently support multiple EC2 SSH keys.